# AWK Merge line accumulator not working

Tags: awk

Below is a single record split over 2 lines with an embedded newline after field 3 (the blank line is the embedded newline)

```
peter,9,ghi

mno
```

The algorithm is if there are less than 4 fields in a record then continue merging subsequent lines until you have 4 fields, then output the record.

I have awk code that supposedly does this. 2 cases.

**CASE 1**

```
> If the number of fields in the current line plus the accumulated
> number of fields = 4 then     if there were no previous fields 
>        print current line      else 
>       print previously accumulated line plus current line
```

**CASE 2** Append the current line to the accumulated previous lines

```
BEGIN {
  FS=","
  flds=4
  prevF=0
}
flds == NF + prevF {
                    print (prevF==0) ?  $0 :  prevLine $0
                    prevF=0
                    prevLine=""
                    next
                   }
{prevLine = (prevF==0) ? $0 FS : prevLine $0
 prevF = prevF + NF}
```

Simple enough algorithm. When I run it against the data snippet I get

```
,mnohi,9,ghi
```

instead of the 2nd line tacked on to the end of the first.

I am interested in understanding why the code is behaving as it is and in awk solutions.

Comment: Not clear, please add proper sample(s) input and expected output in code tags in your post too and let us know then.

Comment: Sounds like your input file contains control-Ms, Use `cat -v` to see them then dos2unix or similar to remove them then tell us if you still have a problem or not.

Comment: That was it. Thanks.